# MQTT pub/sub communication format

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, beagleboneblack

I want to use MQTT protocol for communication using gsm module and raspberry-pi/beaglebone . As gsm provide tcp connection via AT commands. Can someone tell me what is the format for publishing to a mqtt broker?

I am using a beaglebone with a gsm module for tcp connection. I have connected different sensors and want to transmit the  generated and manipulated  data to a broker. But the problem with gsm is that it transmit data via tcp exchange So I would have to do a low level networking(like sockets) with them. So lets say if we have only socket connection availabe with no protocol. How will I implement mqtt protocol over it?

Any help would be nice..

Comment: Have you tried searching the mqtt docs?

Comment: As it stands this question is way too broad, you need to outline what you have already tried and then somebody can help if you have a problem. To get you started the MQTT spec can be found here: http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html

Comment: I am using a beaglebone with a gsm module for tcp connection. I have connected different sensors and want to transmit the  generated and manipulated  data to a broker. But the problem with gsm is that it transmit data via tcp exchange So I would have to do a low level networking(like sockets) with them. So lets say if we have only socket connection availabe with no protocol. How will I implement mqtt protocol over it.

Comment: @ShashankJaiswal, repeating what is in your question will not help. You must start searching for a solution e.g. in the link that hardillb showed you. Nobody will write the code for you, it's more to help you/point you where to get help, or answering concrete questions about specific code.

Comment: You could use one of the paho mqtt client libraries, e.g. python https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/ but there are also c, java, javascript, etc., assuming where this is going to run (the beaglebone?) has the services needed by the client, the libraries then handle the connection details and then you publish data which is taken as binary to the broker, and the subscribers get the same data, i.e. the same binary. So your publisher and subscriber have to have a common understanding of the content format or encoding, whether that is text, or jpeg picture, or a sample of audio.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Beaglebone why to worry about MQTT implementation. Connect you BB to internet using PPP Dialer/Wvdial. Use [Paho Python Client](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/) and develop an application to publish your sensor data to cloud.